# NTFS symlink not syncing to target folder

Tags: sync, ntfs, symbolic-link, onedrive, my-documents

In Windows 7, I've created a directory symlink in my SkyDrive folder that points to my My Documents folder. In other words, I have the following folders:

```
c:\users\<user name>\documents
c:\users\<user name>\skydrive\my documents
```

In this way, I can sync the contents of my My Documents folder to SkyDrive.

However, if I create a new folder in the link folder, it does not get synced to the target folder. For example, I created the following new folder:

```
c:\users\<user name>\skydrive\my documents\<client name>\<project name>
```

I would expect that I'll also see the following new folder:

```
c:\users\<user name>\documents\<client name>\<project name>
```

However, the new folder doesn't show up in the target folder.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a SymLink, I think you need to create a directory Junction.

> mklink /J "c:\users\<user name>\documents" "c:\users\<user name>\skydrive\documents"

This article seems to confirm my hunch ...
 
http://janhannemann.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/sync-any-folder-to-skydrive/